# Android TextView setTextSize incorrectly increases text size

Tags: android, textview, pixel, pixelformat

This is in an extension of TextView. `getTextSize()` and `setTextSize()` are not overridden, I do not extend those methods. Programming in 1.6, API level 4.

The loop in this code causes size to be multiplied by 1.5 every time it iterates, e.g. if size initially reads 200 from `getTextSize`, then `setTextSize(size)` is called, `getTextSize` called again reads back 300.

```
public void shrinkTest() {
    float size = this.getTextSize(); 
    while (size > 8) {
        this.setTextSize(size);
        size = this.getTextSize();
    }
}
```

Why is this?

Answer (score 162, accepted):

Heh, mixed units problem. Seems a little counterintuitive, but it's an easy fix. The default method `setTextSize(float)` assumes you're inputting `sp` units (scaled pixels), while the `getTextSize()` method returns an exact pixel size.

You can fix this by using the alternate `setTextSize(TypedValue, float)`, like so:

```
this.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_PX, size);
```

This will make sure you're working with the same units.

Answer (score 23):

`setTextSize()` and `getTextSize()` work with different units. The parameter to set() is density-independent "scaled pixels", whereas get() returns plain old pixels.

Comment: Hah, thought that only ever happened to me! Have an upvote for your slightly more useful answer...

Answer (score 5):

pass units with size using TypedValue like below:

TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_PX   //Pixels

TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_SP   //Scaled Pixels

TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP  //Device Independent Pixels

setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_SP, 18)