# How to set text size of textview dynamically for different screens

Tags: android

I am creating a textview and adding to the layout dynamically. I am using `textView.setTextSize(18)` method to set the text size.I tested it on samsung tablet and found that the font size is too small for this screen then I changed the textsize to 25 but it is too big for an emulator(480*800). My problem is to set text size dynamically so that it fits for all the screens.

Comment: but this question title is perfect compared to duplicate

Answer (score 168, accepted):

You should use the resource folders such as

```
values-ldpi
values-mdpi
values-hdpi
```

And write the text size in 'dimensions.xml' file for each range.

And in the java code you can set the text size with

```
textView.setTextSize(getResources().getDimension(R.dimen.textsize));
```

Sample dimensions.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <dimen name="textsize">15sp</dimen>
</resources>
```

Comment: can you give me an example to write dimensions.xml file

Comment: Probably no need for the DPI qualifier if the dimension is specified in sp as they are scaled by the screen density (and user preferred font size).

Comment: Isn't DP better than SP? Will the above work for this issue: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18497760/having-an-issue-with-textsize-within-textview

Comment: ITs also worked with `dimens.xml`

Comment: text size looks very large with this method.

Comment: Actually, you need textView.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_PX, getResources().getDimension(R.dimen.textsize));

Answer (score 305):

EDIT:
And As I Search on StackOverflow now I found **This Question is Duplicate of** : [**This**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3687065/textview-settextsize-behaves-abnormally) and [**This**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5032355/android-textview-settextsize-incorrectly-increases-text-size)

You need to use another function `setTextSize(unit, size)` with unit `SP` like this,

```
tv.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_SP, 18f);
```

Please read more for **[TypedValue](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/TypedValue.html)** constants.

Comment: I think your answer is not good. Better use value from dimens.xml

Answer (score 68):

There is probably no need to use the `ldpi` , `mdpi` or `hdpi` qualifiers in this case.

When you define a dimension in a resource file you include the measurement unit. If you use sp units they are scaled according to the screen density so text at 15sp should appear roughly the same size on screens of differing density.
(The real screen density of the device isn't going to exactly match as Android generalises screen density into `120, 160, 240, 320, 480 and 640 dpi` groups.)

When calling `getResources().getDimension(R.dimen.textsize)` it will return the size in pixels. If using sp it will scaled by the screen density,

Calling `setText(float)` sets the size in `sp units`. This is where the issue is,
**i.e** you have pixels measurements on one hand and `sp unit` on the other to fix do this:

```
textView.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_PX,
    getResources().getDimension(R.dimen.textsize));
```

Note you can also use

```
getResources().getDimensionPixelSize(R.dimen.textSize);
```

instead of `getDimension()` and it will round and convert to an non fractional value.

Answer (score 51):

After long time stuck this issue, finally solved like this

```
textView.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_PX,
              getResources().getDimension(R.dimen.textsize));
```

create folder  like this `res/values/dimens.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>

  <dimen name="textsize">8sp</dimen>

 </resources>
```

Comment: Why TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_PX and now TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_SP?

Comment: Where exactly we need to create dimen folder?

Comment: @SudarshanTaparia create folder here res/values/dimens.xml and add your text size.

Answer (score 4):

In Style.xml pre-define the style:

```
<style name="largeText">
    <item name="android:textAppearance">@android:style/TextAppearance.Large.Inverse</item>
    <item name="android:textStyle">bold</item>
</style>
```

in code:

```
text.setTextAppearance(context, R.style.largeText);
```

Comment: How do you customize the size measurement of largeText?

Answer (score -2):

I think You should use the textView.setTextSize(float size) method to set the size of text. textView.setText(arg) used to set the text in the Text View.

Comment: Android Text size will be always specifying in sp, not in dp or float values

Answer (score -8):

```
float currentSize = textEdit.getTextSize(); // default size
float newSize = currentSize * 2.0F; // new size is twice bigger than default one
textEdit.setTextSize(newSize);
```

Comment: I don't see any consideration for the screen size in this answer.

Comment: In my opinion the question is about font size. So I don't understand why you complain about absence of references to sceen size.
Default font has appropriate size in most of cases. So it is better to think about font size in terms of bigger/smaller default size, i.e. independetly of screen size. So I wrote a solution which can be used to set font size relative to default font size.