# how to support multi screen size in android apps

Tags: android, multiscreen

I write an application in android. now i want to change my code to be suitable for multi screens. i search but i didn't completely understand what should i do for that?
for example:

1- i should [set text size dynamically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9494037/how-to-set-text-size-of-textview-dynamically-for-diffrent-screens)

2- [have different layout for different screens size](http://developer.samsung.com/android/technical-docs/Handling-Multiple-Screen-Size-in-Android)

is there additional work to do?
any sample for my question?

Comment: see this link it ia an article which i read prviously for supporting multiple screen sizes.  http://www.androidguys.com/2010/02/23/handling-multiple-screen-sizes-part-3/

Answer (score 0):

Building a Dynamic UI with Fragments...just use fragments in your application to make it flexible  http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html         http://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/index.html