# Trying to display text of different sizes on button click in Android app

Tags: android, textview

Once I click the button, I want text of different sizes to be displayed. I tried using the built-in html support for it but I found out that font size tag is not supporI'm using a TextView to do this but I keep getting an error saying "could not execute method of the activity".

Here is my activity main part:

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/header"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textSize="32px" />

<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/rams" 
    android:onClick="ramsShow" />
```

I have the header string resource in string.xml:

```
<string name="header">Header</string>
```

This is the method in my MainActivity that is called when the button is clicked:

```
public void ramsShow(View view)
{
    TextView test= new TextView(this);
    test = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.header);
    String tmp = "hi";
    test.setText(tmp);
}
```

Comment: remove this line `TextView test= new TextView(this);`

Comment: What size are you talking about? Do you want different sizes for different screens or just want to change the size??

Answer (score 0):

As Ketan suggested you should have:

```
public void ramsShow(View view)
{
    TextView test = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.header);
    String tmp = "hi";
    test.setText(tmp);
}
```

To adjust sizes have a look here: [How to set text size of textview dynamically for different screens](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9494037/how-to-set-text-size-of-textview-dynamically-for-diffrent-screens)

Answer (score 0):

In Activity class, above the `onCreate` Method, add this line.

```
TextView test = null;
```

Within `onCreate` method, add this code

```
test = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.header);
```

Idea is to move the line from `ramsShow` method to `onCreate` method.

Comment: Thanks ketan ... Initialized null value.hope this fixes it. If missing something else, feel free to edit my answer

Comment: removed `final` as you can not reinitialize final variable.

Answer (score 0):

Within onCreate() write this code...

RelativeLayout lView = new RelativeLayout(this);

```
            myText = new TextView(this);
            myText.setText(Html.fromHtml("<b><center><font size='3'><font color=\"#145A14\">Welcome standard\n"</font></font></center></b>"));
lView.addView(myText);
```

setContentView(lView);
}