# How to change the size of an item in a ListView dynamically?

Tags: java, android, xml, listview, items

I have a `ListView` with my own XML. It contains a `TextView`. There can be 1 up to 6 lines of text.

The problem is that it shows only 2 lines of text. How can I change the size of an item in a `ListView` dynamically to show the whole text?

My xml, where `txt2` contains 1-6 line of text:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    >
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/img"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:contentDescription="Test"
        android:paddingTop="10dp"
        android:paddingRight="10dp"
        android:paddingBottom="10dp"
        />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        >
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txt"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textSize="18dp"
            android:textColor="#000000"
            />
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txt2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textSize="14dp"
            android:textColor="#000000"
            />
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to set text size of textview dynamically for diffrent screens](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9494037/how-to-set-text-size-of-textview-dynamically-for-diffrent-screens)

Comment: you have 1-6 lines of text in a textview right?

Comment: Change Main `LinearLayout` height to `wrap_content` and Check.

Comment: Also paste Listview all attributes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 android:layout_width="match_parent"
 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
 android:orientation="horizontal"
 >
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/img"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:contentDescription="Test"
    android:paddingTop="10dp"
    android:paddingRight="10dp"
    android:paddingBottom="10dp"
    />

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    >
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txt"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="18dp"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        />
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txt2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="14dp"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        />
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use for `Textview` 
`android:singleLine="false"`

Answer (score 0):

Use this to calculate dynamically change

```
String abc ="text which you will use";
TextView textView = null; // assign here
textView.setMaxLines(abc.length()/ 40);
textView.setMinLines(abc.length()/ 40);
```

Answer (score 0):

Make your list view to be horizontally scrollable

i.e.

Add your

```
 <ListView> inside <HorizontalScrollView>
```

Now you can horizontally scroll to see full text...

Answer (score 0):

You can also Just give a fixed

> layout_width for TextView.

And the whole 1-6 lines of text will wrap to according to height...