# TextView Width is not adjusting as the content inside it even after wrap content

Tags: android, android-layout, textview

I have a text inside TextView which I want to be in single line on larger screen sizes devices and two lines on smaller screen size devices. I also have an image on right of it.

Now the issue is the size of TextView is coming bigger than the content inside it, even it is a wrap content, which creates extra unnecessary space between textview and image view.

**My Code :**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="60dp"
        android:background="#FFFFFF"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:paddingLeft="40dp"
        android:paddingRight="40dp"
        >


        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Please Fit my width according tothecontentinsideme"
            android:textColor="#000000"
            android:background="#11DDFF"
            android:textSize="22sp"
            android:fontFamily="din-condensed"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/rightArrowImage"
            android:textStyle="bold"/>

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/rightArrowImage"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:src="@drawable/scoretracker_reedem_rewards_arrow"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            />


    </RelativeLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

**Output :**
[image: Layout Image]

**UPDATE**

I tried what dieter_h suggested

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="60dp"
        android:background="#FFFFFF"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:paddingLeft="40dp"
        android:paddingRight="40dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        >


        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Please Fit my width according tothecontentinsideme"
            android:textColor="#000000"
            android:background="#11DDFF"
            android:textSize="22sp"
            android:textStyle="bold"/>

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/rightArrowImage"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:src="@drawable/scoretracker_reedem_rewards_arrow"
            />


    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

**OUTPUT NOW :**

[image]

Comment: put a margin in TextView not in ImageView

Comment: In which layout , Linear one or Relative one ? BTW I have tried in both same results no difference.

Comment: Hold on I'll put my answer in a few minutes..

Comment: Let me know it it was what you was asking for :)

Comment: The longer I look at the pictures the more I think that the width of TextView measured with wrap_content is simply not enough to fit into the room left after ImageView's width and margins all together. By me it's an expected behavior which is not observed once the text size is smaller. Say, are those pictures taken from a phone screen in portrait mode?

Comment: Well, if I'm right, without overriding any methods of View, you could decrease margins and text size, or create different layouts for different screen sizes, letting a single line of text for bigger sizes and 2 lines for smaller ones.

Answer (score 0):

Try this `xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="60dp"
        android:background="#FFFFFF"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:paddingLeft="20dp"
        android:paddingRight="20dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        >
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="301dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Please Fit my width according tothecontentinsideme"
            android:textColor="#000000"
            android:id="@+id/TextView2"
            android:background="#11DDFF"
            android:textSize="22sp"
            android:textStyle="bold"/></LinearLayout>
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/rightArrowImage"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher"

        />
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

This is how it looks :

[image]

### Final EDIT

I made a new `xml` try this out

```
    <?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="#fff"
    android:paddingLeft="20dp"
    android:paddingRight="20dp"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:background="#fff"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        tools:ignore="DisableBaselineAlignment" >



        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center"

            android:layout_weight="0.5"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            >

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textColor="#000"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:textSize="15sp"
                android:background="#11DDFF"
                android:text="Please Fit my width according tothecontentinsideme"
                tools:ignore="HardcodedText"
                android:id="@+id/textViewTitleDialog"
                />

        </LinearLayout>
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"

            android:gravity="center"
            android:orientation="horizontal" >

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:contentDescription="@string/app_name"

                android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
                android:id="@+id/asd" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

This is the output

[image]

Hope it is what you want :)

Comment: Thank you, I have copy pasted your code as it is, but here results are same as my earlier one. I am wondering why ? Put your entire xml once .

Comment: Hey you have fixed the width, I knew this trick but the problem is it will not come in single line for bigger screen size, which is what I require.

Comment: Try my old one, if you put 10sp it will fit

Comment: No, I dont want this way. The extra space in left image I don't want. Width should be till the text ends. I think with xml we cannot solve this. Need to override TextView onMeasure(), But I have no idea how can I achieve my required results doing that.

Comment: well.. I tried my best I'm out of ideas... if you want to override the onMeasure() just take a look on this answers [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9494037/how-to-set-text-size-of-textview-dynamically-for-different-screens), [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15323079/4385913)

Comment: @pyus13 Solved it? You didn't mark any answer as a correct