# Get the font size using autoSize

Tags: android, textview

Im using a `TextView` with the property `autoSizeTextType="uniform"`.

The font size its ok, but now, I need to get the current size, but Im always getting "328", so this size does not correspond with the displayed size.

Any idea of how to get the size?

Comment: check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37789282/how-to-auto-size-textview-dynamically-according-to-the-length-of-the-text-in-and

Comment: Thanks but this question is different, I need to get the value like "getFontSize" using "autoSizeTextType"

Answer (score 0):

You should wait for view update after set text before geting text size; Use `TextView.post` to do this.

Example:

```kotlin
fun setText(longText: String) {
    mTextView.textSize // return 18

    mTextView.text = longText
    mTextView.textSize // still 18

    mTextView.post {
        mTextView.textSize // return 11
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

If you look at the [getTextSize()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView#getTextSize()), it returns the text size in pixel so If you want the text size in **sp**(sp is the most commonly used textSize unit) then you can use the method given below.

```
public static int getSPfromPX(int px) {
        int sizeValue;
        float sp = TypedValue.applyDimension(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_SP, px, getResources().getDisplayMetrics());
        sizeValue = (int) Math.ceil(sp);
        return sizeValue;
    }
```

And here is it's Kotlin variant

```
fun getSPfromPX(px: Int): Int {
        val sizeValue: Int
        val sp = TypedValue.applyDimension(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_SP, px.toFloat(), resources.displayMetrics)
        sizeValue = ceil(sp.toDouble()).toInt()
        return sizeValue
    }
```

Comment: This not works using autosize, the textview returns a size different that the displayed text (always the same) using 100 characters or 10, I hope I have explained this as best I can.