# Bigger menus for bigger screens

Tags: android, android-menu

I am setting my mobile app to work in tablets, one of the many things that need to be tweaked is the fon t size of menus which in an 10" screen are too small. So I'm  looking for a global variable that change that font size like you can do with `textViews` and similar things with

`<dimen name="size_font_view_tex">21sp</dimen>`

inside dimens-wXXXdp/dimens.xml

Anybody know the name (if it is) of the dimen resource that changes the size of menus?

Bonus: List of all dimen resources

Comment: use layout variation to create different flavours for different sizes.

Comment: the point is that android will use different values for different screen sizes, also 'm wiling to change 1 line in 1 xml and not rewrite 50 layout files

Answer (score 0):

You have to use the different layouts for different size of screen.As you stated the  10" screen you have to make the folder layout-large in your res folder and make the layout according to need. Hope this will help you.

Comment: In android as you can set a layout-wXXXdp folder you also can specify a dimens-wXXXdp folder and specify setting as font size globally instead of change every layout iam looking for the right property, anyways, thanks for your time!

Answer (score 0):

form [How to set text size of textview dynamically for different screens](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9494091/7267105)

You should use the resource folders such as

```
values-ldpi
values-mdpi
values-hdpi
```

And write the text size in '`dimensions.xml`' file for each range.

And in the java code you can set the text size with

```
textView.setTextSize(getResources().getDimension(R.dimen.textsize));
```

Sample dimensions.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <dimen name="textsize">15sp</dimen>
</resources>
```

Comment: thats also wont work, there is no point in declare a dimen value if you have to manually code all elements one by one

Answer (score 0):

When you create a new layout with right click, you can manage this creation with a "available qualifers".

Here for size, keep the qualifer size and set the screen size that you want.

For example you can set x-large to create a tablet layout for the same screen that you already created before.

more explain : https://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html