# Make TextView with drawable expand inside CardView

Tags: android, android-layout, textview, android-cardview, material-components-android

I'm trying to make a `TextView` that contains a text and a drawable expand/scale based on the size of the `TextView`. My current code:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fillViewport="true"
    tools:context=".activity.WelcomeActivity">

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/title_view"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:text="Example"
            android:textSize="30sp"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

        <com.google.android.material.card.MaterialCardView
            android:id="@+id/cardStart"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
            app:layout_constraintDimensionRatio="1"
            android:layout_gravity="fill"
            app:cardCornerRadius="8dp"
            app:cardElevation="8dp"
            app:cardUseCompatPadding="true"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/title_view"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/txtCardStart"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:text="@string/card_start"
                android:textAlignment="center"
                app:drawableTopCompat="@drawable/ic_baseline_start_24" />
        </com.google.android.material.card.MaterialCardView>

    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

which looks good, but small:

[image]

and when I make the `TextView` take more space it doesn't scale proportionally, but rather stays as big as drawable height and width is defined in `ic_baseline_start_24`:

```xml
<vector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:width="50dp"
    android:height="50dp"
    android:viewportWidth="24"
    android:viewportHeight="24"
    android:tint="?attr/colorControlNormal">
    <path
        android:fillColor="@android:color/white"
        android:pathData="M14.59,7.41L18.17,11H6v2h12.17l-3.59,3.59L16,18l6,-6l-6,-6L14.59,7.41zM2,6v12h2V6H2z" />
</vector>
```

Is this possible with `TextEdit` or I'd need to separate an `ImageView` and a `TextView`? My goal is to see it like this

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use MaterialButton instead of MaterialCardView like below:

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fillViewport="true"
    tools:context=".activity.WelcomeActivity">

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/title_view"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
            android:text="Example"
            android:textSize="30sp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />


        <com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton
            android:id="@+id/txtCardStart"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_gravity="fill"
            android:backgroundTint="@color/gray_light"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:text="Start"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            app:cornerRadius="8dp"
            app:cardElevation="8dp"
            android:textSize="24sp"
            app:cardUseCompatPadding="true"
            app:icon="@drawable/ic_baseline_start_24"
            app:iconGravity="textTop"
            app:iconSize="100dp"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintDimensionRatio="1"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/title_view" />


    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

note that you can set textSize and iconSize as you wish.

**-UPDATE-**

If you want to use MaterialCardView you can use these codes:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fillViewport="true"
    tools:context=".activity.WelcomeActivity">

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/title_view"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
            android:text="Example"
            android:textSize="30sp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

        <com.google.android.material.card.MaterialCardView
            android:id="@+id/cardStart"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_gravity="fill"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
            app:cardCornerRadius="8dp"
            app:cardElevation="8dp"
            app:cardUseCompatPadding="true"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintDimensionRatio="1"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/title_view">

            <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center">

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/imageView"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="0dp"
                    android:background="@drawable/ic_baseline_start_24"
                    app:layout_constraintDimensionRatio="1:1"
                    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintWidth_percent="0.6" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/txtCardStart"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:text="Start"
                    android:textAlignment="center"
                    android:textStyle="bold"
                    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/imageView" />

        </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>


    </com.google.android.material.card.MaterialCardView>

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

As can be seen, I use an ImageView and set layout_constraintWidth_percent sixty percent of parent width. As a result, the ImageView size is changed dynamically. but steel the font size of the TextView is fixed. you can change it dynamically using [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9494097/12500284)

Comment: Isn't there a way with `MaterialCardView`? Also when expanding this button, it doesn't expand/scale automatically the drawable. How can I indicate that the drawable takes a proportion of the parent widget, so when scaling it up the drawable also scales up

Comment: Thanks that tackles my concern. I wonder why it isn't scaled the TextView automatically, and we need to change it programmatically. It seems very ugly and unelegant

Comment: I agree, but nowadays Compose covers the xml shortcomings.