# Why is TextView.setTextSize() not recalculating the TextView's height correctly?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-4.0-ice-cream-sandwich

Several of us have TextViews that have the text size set in code, however in Android 4.0 / ICS once the TextView has sized itself for bigger text it will not reduce it's size again after the text size is set smaller.

Someone else has posted an app ilustrating the problem on the android issue tracker here:-
 http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=22493

It works in android froyo and GB, but in 4.0 displays this issue.

There are a couple of work-arounds listed there, but I'm not sure this is the way to go. Can anyone explain the cause / provide a workaround and explanation of why it works?

- Anthony

Comment: Please refer this link:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5032355/android-textview-settextsize-incorrectly-increases-text-size

Comment: Just run into this.  Looks like it's down as fixed in 4.1 but I will need to try the workarounds for now by the look of things.