# Problems increasing text size in my app

Tags: android, android-widget, textview

I'm trying to increase the size of a particular textview from within the app. I would like to do it via a menu item selection but am having problems. I have tried the following:

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) 
{
    // Create an options menu for the activity
    super.onCreateOptionsMenu( menu );

    incrseTxtMenu = menu.add( 0,4,0,"Increase Text Size" );
    incrseTxtMenu.setIcon( R.drawable.ic_menu_plus );
    incrseTxtMenu.setOnMenuItemClickListener( new MenuItem.OnMenuItemClickListener() 
    {
        @Override
        public boolean onMenuItemClick(MenuItem item) 
        {
            // handler.sendMessage( handler.obtainMessage() );
            TextView tempTxt = getTextView();
            tempTxt.setTextSize( 25 );

            return true;
        }
    });

    return true;
}
```

But this is throwing a null pointer exception. I also tried just using intro.setTextSize() but it throws the same error. How can I access the textview from within this menu item?

**Update

```
//Method used to fetch the textview
public TextView getTextView()
{
    return intro;
}
```

And the error from log cat:

```
AndroidRuntime FATAL EXCEPTION: main
java.lang.NullPointerException
at android.omni.Artist_activity$1.handleMessage( Artist_activity.java:32 )
```

Also btw - I'm trying to use a handler to update the GUI - am I correct in assuming that this is necessary right?

**Update 2 XML CODE

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <ScrollView
      xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      android:id = "@+id/tab_one_top_level"
      android:layout_width="fill_parent"
      android:layout_height="fill_parent">

      <LinearLayout
      android:orientation = "vertical"
      android:layout_width="fill_parent"
      android:layout_height="fill_parent">

      <TextView

    android:id = "@+id/faq_Intro"
    android:layout_width = "wrap_content"
    android:layout_height = "wrap_content"
    android:text = "@string/faq_Intro"
    android:typeface = "monospace"
    android:textStyle = "bold"
    android:paddingBottom = "12dp"

      />

      <TextView

    android:id = "@+id/faq_Intro_Info"
    android:layout_width = "wrap_content"
    android:layout_height = "wrap_content"
    android:text = "@string/faq_Intro_Info"
    android:textSize = "10dp"
    android:typeface = "monospace"
    android:textStyle = "bold"

      />

      </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Any thoughts?

***My Code Solution***

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) 
{
    // Create an options menu for the activity
    super.onCreateOptionsMenu( menu );

    incrseTxtMenu = menu.add( 0,1,0,"Increase Text Size" );
    incrseTxtMenu.setIcon( R.drawable.ic_menu_plus );

    decrseTxtMenu = menu.add( 0,2,0,"Decrease Text Size" );
    decrseTxtMenu.setIcon( R.drawable.ic_menu_negate );

    return true;

}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) 
{
    // Increase size menu item
    if( item.getItemId() == 1 )
    {
        intro.setTextSize( myIntroSize += 5 );
        introInfo.setTextSize( myIntroInfoSize += 5 );

    }
    // Derease size menu item
    else if( item.getItemId() == 2 )
    {
        intro.setTextSize( myIntroSize -= 5 );
        introInfo.setTextSize( myIntroInfoSize -= 5 );
    }
    return true;
}
```

The onCreate() method simply initialises the textview as before. Oh and the values of myIntroSize and myIntroInfoSize can be whatever you want.

Comment: what is getTextView()? Can you please post the error from the Log Cat?

Comment: what is htese lines TextView tempTxt = getTextView(); in your code

Comment: That was an experiment which just returns a textview - I have updated my code above

Comment: So what is on Line 32 of Artist_activity.java? Where is the `intro` variable instantiated?

Comment: In the onCreate() method like this: intro = (TextView)findViewById( R.id.faq_intro ), you know the usual way

Comment: And the id `faq_intro` is in your XML? What is on line 32? Thats your NPE

Comment: You want to change the textsize of a TextView when the user tabs on a menu item? No you do not need a Handler. You need a handler when you want to run code outside of the UI thread and get notified to update the UI when that code finished. Your Exception comes from your Handler

Comment: I tried removing the handler part and just using intro.setTextSize() and get the same NPE, therefore it's not the handler doing it

Comment: @Katana24 As you can see in your stack trace your exception is caused by your `handleMessage()` method. When you removed the handler..that exception can not been thrown from that method anymore because that method does not exist anymore. So you can't get "the same NPE"

Comment: well i didn't mean the exact same one - i just meant a NPE in general. My bad

Comment: No problem. Edit your post and show us the NPE you get without using Handler in your code

Comment: I found the solution - it's my fault for not providing enough info. This particular activity is a TabActivity. The view exists within one of the tabs, or so I thought. I applied the same layout to both tabs but when I changed the code slightly and clicked on the other tab it was updating there and not on the first tab. Not really sure as to why though...

Comment: I have updated my code above to include my final solution to this though I have accepted another answer... Well tried to but couldn't get at it :D

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please try the following code and tell me if it works. I don't know what is wrong, it's just based on a few hunches -

```
    @Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) 
{
    // Create an options menu for the activity
    super.onCreateOptionsMenu( menu );

    incrseTxtMenu = menu.add( 0,4,0,"Increase Text Size" );
    incrseTxtMenu.setIcon( R.drawable.ic_menu_plus );
    return true;
}


@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    if(item.getItemId() == 4){
         TextView tempTxt =  (TextView)findViewById( R.id.faq_intro);
            tempTxt.setTextSize( 25 );
    }

}
```

Comment: Yes mate that works fine though I would suggest adding to the existing value in setTextSize instead of just 25. Thanks for the help mate :D

Answer (score 2):

This snippet is working fine with me, try it. I guess your problem in how you get the TextView itself. " you should use `findViewbyId(int id)` "

```
     @Override
            public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
            // Create an options menu for the activity
            super.onCreateOptionsMenu( menu );

            MenuItem incrseTxtMenu = menu.add( 0,4,0,"Increase Text Size" );
            incrseTxtMenu.setIcon( android.R.drawable.btn_plus );
            incrseTxtMenu.setOnMenuItemClickListener( new MenuItem.OnMenuItemClickListener() 
            {
                @Override
                public boolean onMenuItemClick(MenuItem item) 
                {
                    TextView tempTxt = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text);
                    tempTxt.setTextSize( 25 );

                    return true;
                }
            });

        return true;
    }
```

Also its better to handle the menu selections using this function:

```
  @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
```

not using setOnMenuItemClickListener

edit: I am not using any handlers

Comment: Why not use setOnMenuItemClickListener? Can you provide any resources to verify this?

Comment: My reference: the android documentation: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/MenuItem.html  Scroll down to setOnMenuItemClickListener you will read "it is more efficient and easier to use onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem)"

Comment: Cool - though I wish they would give a reason. Thanks mate

Comment: Just different implementations for different people I guess.

Answer (score 1):

I believe your problem is when you are calling "getTextView();"

```
TextView tempTxt = getTextView();
tempTxt.setTextSize( 25 );
```

Also, when you set the size of your text, you should use this to make sure they are pixels:

```
tempTxt.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_PX, 25);
```

Read here:
 [TextView.setTextSize behaves abnormally - How to set text size of textview dynamically for different screens](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3687065/textview-settextsize-behaves-abnormally)
 [Android TextView setTextSize incorrectly increases text size](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5032355/android-textview-settextsize-incorrectly-increases-text-size)

It is best if objects that are created have an ID from the XML by using "findViewById":

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
// Create an options menu for the activity
super.onCreateOptionsMenu( menu );

MenuItem incrseTxtMenu = menu.add( 0,4,0,"Increase Text Size" );
incrseTxtMenu.setIcon( android.R.drawable.btn_plus );
incrseTxtMenu.setOnMenuItemClickListener( new MenuItem.OnMenuItemClickListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onMenuItemClick(MenuItem item) {
    TextView text = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.faq_Intro); //faq_Intro from XML
    tempTxt.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_PX, 25); //corrected

    return true;
    }
});

return true;
}
```

Also instead of using "OnMenuItemCLickListener", you can easily use "onOptionsItemSelected" with a case switch:

```
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()){

    case R.id.increasesize:  
         //some code
         break;     

    case R.id.exit:  
        finish();
        break;         

    default:
        return true;
    }
```